# Where do files go to be found in the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So I'm pretty new working with Python and Pillow. I'm trying to just load a test image and show it, but it's telling me that it can't find the directory or file. I put the image right next to the script in the same folder, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I've tried putting a direct path to the image ("C:\Users...etc"), but it just gives me a different unicode error.

```py
from PIL import Image;

trophy_img = Image.open('Trophy.jpg');
trophy_img.show();
```

Here's the error message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/Scripts/Pillow_Test/PILTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    trophy_img = Image.open('Trophy.jpg');
  File "C:\Users\Tallen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2652, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Trophy.jpg'
```

Comment: Remove all the semi-colons - they are not needed.

Comment: How are you running the script? Try starting a Command Prompt, and changing directory to your Desktop with `cd Desktop`. Then run with `python yourScript.py`.

Comment: Put `import os ; os.getcwd()` into your script _before_ opening the image, so that you can know where  Python is looking for your file...

Comment: Use the full path to the image file, but prefix the string with an `r` character. i.e. `r"C:\Users...etc")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this, you'll want to know
what your [current working directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) is:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Possibly you would prefer to [change directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)
somewhere before attempting the open().

> a direct path to the image (`"C:\Users...etc"`)

The quoting doesn't look quite right, there.
Consider using a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=raw#string-and-bytes-literals): `r'C:\Users\foo\bar'`.
Or, better, avoid backwhacks entirely: `'C:/Users/foo/bar'`.

Comment: Ok so I did that and it's telling me that it's in my C:\\Users\Tallen folder. How do I change that to be where my script is?

Answer (score 0):

So user  martineau helped me out. Putting an r'C:\Users...etc' solved the issue. I tried running this code previously but I put a space after the r and it didn't work. So thank you guys for helping me out.

```py
from PIL import Image

trophy_img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Tallen\Desktop\Scripts\Pillow_Test\Trophy.jpg');
trophy_img.show()
```

Comment: Indeed. Consider using a raw string: r'C:\Users\foo\bar'. Glad you found it helpful.